# Regex: give alternative order precedence over capturing position

Tags: regex

In a regex, I would like to give the position in an alternative higher precedence that the starting position of the match. For example, the regex `(?:A|B).*Q` for `ABQ` will return

- `ABQ` for a string `asdfABQasdf`
- `BAQ` for a string `asdfBAQasdf`

Is there a way to return only `AQ` in the second case? So only use the second alternative (`B`) if the first alternative does not yield anything?

Comment: Your expected result for `BABQ` would be `ABQ`?

Comment: Try [`(?:B(?!.*A.*Q)|A).*Q`](https://regex101.com/r/kKB5Ij/2). Or `(?:B(?![^ABQ]*A[^QB]*Q)|A)[^ABQ]*Q`. What is the real use case?

Comment: It depends on your programming language, but most "regex match" functions will always return the position of the first match, not of the shortest one (or any other custom precedence). Probably you should really just use `if /A.*Q/.test(str) { … } else if /B.*Q/.test(str) { … }`

Comment: I'm trying to find pair of parenthesis in a LaTeX document (using  Python 3). Unfortunately thing like open intervals may appear, e.g. `]7;8[`. When I try to search for everything at once, multiple of these in succession yield wrong results. I'll simply run multiple of these and then chose the "best" one.